# How do select all p tags using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to **know how to select all p tags** using **JavaScript**. So I can style them if a condition is true or false .

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p')`

Comment: What exactly is your question? You select `p` tags by replacing `div` by `p` in the method call. How does the code relate to your question? What does dark mode have to do with it? What doesn’t work? What’s the desired result?

Comment: Ive also used that still did not work.

Comment: [_What_ did not work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('p') of p elements and styling all existing p tags within the document

Comment: "Did not work" is completely meaningless. Explain your problem clearly, show us code that you've tried that's relevant to the question you're asking, and show us any errors that you've come across.

Comment: Unless some `<p>` tags are within an `<iframe>`, this _does_ work. Methods like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p")).forEach((p) => p.style.borderBottom = "black 1px solid");` affect all `<p>` tags within the current document. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: The code you had before worked (`const ps =`… and `for(p of ps){`…`}`). Why did you change it to a non-working version? `for(p of p){`…`}` won’t work.

Comment: So you decided to make the question “more clear” by removing any details so far? Your current question can be answered with CSS: `body.someClassName p { /* The styles. */ }` and JS: `document.body.classList.toggle("someClassName", someCondition);`. Let CSS do the job of selecting all `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

this will gets all p tags on page, which you can use it as per requirement

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
alert(list.length);
```

But, as per requirement, you need to change from dark mode to light mode.
my suggestion would be to keep on persistence flag. based on flag state. you can load css and make view `p` tag as required via css.

```
p {
 some css property
}
p:hover {
 some css property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are selecting elementsByTagName it will give you an HTML collection. Mostly of the time is not very comfortable to work with or not so self explanatory, maybe you should use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then you could loop it or map it without errors.

If that didn't work. Try using Array.from() on the results, something like this:

```js
let p_elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p'));
p_elements.map(p_element => {
  p.style.color = "red";
})
```

Comment: The code, as originally shown in the question, works. The result being an `HTMLCollection` rather than a `NodeList` doesn’t affect this. Also, you can’t loop over the result of `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 0):

I have Identified my issue the issue was in my JS. I selected my `<p>` tags like so

```
const p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

then just changed it to

```
const ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

then

```
 for(p of ps){
   p.style.color = "#0f0";
 }
```

Afterwards, all `<p>` tags in the document successfully changed color.

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
const ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (div of divs) {
  div.style.borderBottom = "black 1px solid";
}

for (p of ps) {
  p.style.color = "#0f0";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hey</p>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: So all this was caused by a simple typo. As [mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611017/how-do-select-all-p-tags-using-vanilla-javascript#comment117752389_66611017), you can’t use the same variable name for two different things in the same scope like `for (p of p)`.